# Windows Phone 8.1 app to share image - works fine on my phone with Visual Studio debugger attached, but crashes when run without the debugger

Tags: c#, windows, share, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to share an image through my app, everything works just fine when I run the app on my phone through visual studio, but when I try to run it from my phone, it crashes everytime I click the share button

```
  private async void dataTransferManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "Let's Celebrate";
        args.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "It's time to celebrate!";
        DataRequestDeferral deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();
        try
        {
            var finalImg = await GenerateImage();

            var folder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            const CreationCollisionOption option = CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting;
            var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("letscelebrateshare.png", option);
            var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
            var pixelBuffer = await finalImg.GetPixelsAsync();

            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
                encoder.SetPixelData(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                (uint)finalImg.PixelWidth,
                (uint)finalImg.PixelHeight,
                logicalDpi,
                logicalDpi,
                pixelBuffer.ToArray());

                await encoder.FlushAsync();

                StorageFile logoFile =
                    await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("letscelebrateshare.png");
                List<IStorageItem> storageItems = new List<IStorageItem>();
                storageItems.Add(logoFile);
                args.Request.Data.SetStorageItems(storageItems);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            deferral.Complete();
        }

    }
```

Comment: "it crashes" is not a meaningful problem description. What does "crashes" mean? Do you get an exception? If so, what is the exact error message? What does the stack trace tell you about where it happened?

Comment: @KenWhite I can't check what exception this is because, as I mentioned, it runs perfectly error free during the debug stage, but when I disconnect my phone from the laptop, and try to run the app again, it just shuts down when I click the share button

Comment: Then you'll have to insert some code to do some logging or display some message dialogs or something to figure out where it's failing. As I said, "it crashes" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Just a guess: I see there's a lot of async calls, are you touching a UI control from a none-UI thread? That's a typical problem that you often don't see when debugging, because VS will sync with main UI thread when you step through the code. Maybe the deferral is an example of that, or the call to GenerateImage()? Are any UI controls involved in that method?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private async void bla... [..]
{
    Exception exc= null;

    try
    {
    //All your stuff
    }


    catch(Exception ex)
    {

     exc = ex;

    }

    if(exc!=null)
    await msg.ShowAsync();

}
```

Edit: Since I don't use WP in C#. I guess you could try this. Hope this helps ^^

Comment: Windows Phone 8.1 doesn't support Message Box, so I tried using MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog(ex.Message); msg.ShowAsync(); but since ShowAsync is awaitable, and we can't have awaitable methods in catch, the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while opening a file open picker. I found a weird solution. When I removed the navigation parameters in every pages and used static variables instead, worked fine for me. I guess this will help you

Answer (score 0):

If the App is there crashing without debugger, try while debugging and the share targets are visible to "suspend and shutdown" ("Lifecycle Events" in visual studio). In most cases you app will then crash because it is suspended and serialize the data.